# Storing Map with Java Cloudant API

Tags: java, hashmap, cloudant

I am using Java Cloudant API to store data in IBM Cloudant.

I am trying to store `null` value for a key in HashMap in a document.

Following is the code to insert a HashMap in the DB.

```
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 map.put("field1", "value1");
 map.put("field2", null);
 db.save(map);
```

The document is stored successfully, but the document does not contain the field2 key at all.

(i.e.) When the value of a key in a hashmap is null, the corresponding key is not stored in Cloudant.

Any ideas to this.? Where am I going wrong.?

How does Cloudant store Java Objects internally.?

Does it convert Java Objects to String internally?

Comment: you could also make your own object NullObject which could avoid using Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Cloudant doesn't store Java Objects, it is a JSON document store. It uses GSON to serialise Java Objects into a JSON document, so the data it sends to cloudant has the form:

```
{
  "_id": "aDocId",
  "field1": "value1"
 }
```

Looking at the [code for the library](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder.java#L257-L269), it doesn't include the `serializeNulls()` method when creating the GSON builder. You can work around this by providing your own `GsonBuilder` instance to the `ClientBuilder` before calling the `build` method to create the client.

Example:

```
CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account("example")
                           .username("example")
                           .password("password")
                           .gsonBuilder(new GsonBuilder.serializeNulls())
                           .build();
```

However this being said it may cause **errors** and unexpected behaviour, because serialising nulls **has not been tested**.